# spree install undefined method mass_assignment_sanitizer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, installation, spree

I took a look about this problem within the list of question but nothing helped.
This is my first question in stackoverflow so please accept my apologies in case I do something wrong. Also I still have a lot of english to improve.

I'm installing Spree following the github instructions

```
$ gem install spree
$ rails new my_store
$ spree install my_store
```

when I get this message

...

```
Admin Password [spree123] 
gemfile  spree
gemfile  spree_usa_epay
gemfile  spree_skrill
     run  bundle install from "./my_store"
git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git (at 0cb57b4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
precompiling  assets
git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git (at 0cb57b4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

...
Well, as the guide suggests, in case of circular dependency issues do:

```
$ gem install spree_cmd

$spree install my_store -A

gemfile  spree
gemfile  spree_usa_epay
gemfile  spree_skrill
     run  bundle install from "./my_store"
git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git (at 0cb57b4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
precompiling  assets
git://github.com/spree/spree_usa_epay.git (at 0cb57b4) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`
```

I changed directory to the app and run the command:

```
$cd my_store

$bundle install
```

and I get the following error

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
In Gemfile:
spree_usa_epay (>= 0) ruby depends on
  rails (<= 3.1.3, >= 3.1.1) ruby

rails (3.2.1)
```

after this I changed the gem file to work with rails 3.1.3 and coffeescript gems and repeat the whole process again and I get this.

```
Users/Snake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-  3.1.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing': undefined method  `mass_assignment_sanitizer=' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
from /Users/Snake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
```

It think it might be something with version of rails a spree but I don't know were to start.

Does anybody had this issue before?

I running Mac OS X 10.5.8

rails 3.2.1

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i386-darwin9.8.0]

ImageMagick @6.7.4-6_0+q16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Anatoly Ruchka suggested the problem was using rails 3.2.1, so I switched to 3.1.3.

This is what I did, I found a post of @vonconrad where he explain how to create a rail project without touch the installation.

1) I create a directory folder for my project:

```
$mkdir old_rails313
$cd old_rails313
$touch gemfile
$nano gemfile
```

2) 
I pasted a gemfile definition specifying as you mention the version of rails I want, so it looks like this

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.8.0.rc1", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.4.0", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.2.0", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2", :group => :test
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.7.0", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5", :group => :test
#gem "devise", ">= 1.5.0"
gem 'spree','1.0.0'
```

3) then I run

```
bundle install
bundle exec rails new .
rails g spree:install
rails s
```

After installing I've got a conflict with the gem 'spree','1.0.0', so I comment it out.

Also I've got a warning but it works:

```
[DEPRECATION WARNING] Nested I18n namespace lookup under "activerecord.attributes.spree/order" is no longer supported
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: to create an empty file, but you can do it directly with your text editor

Comment: No more conflicts with gem 'spree', '1.0.3'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use rails version 3.1.3 for spree_usa_epay

TO do that you should uninstall all rails what you have on machine

to watch use

```
gem list -d rails
```

than

```
sudo gem uninstall rails -v ...
```

and create new project with

```
rails new my_store
```

than edit Gemfile and paste

gem 'spree', '1.0.0'

and

```
bundle install
```

well done

```
rails server
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints! but I take a second option and don't touch my rails installations. But anyway your answer helped me a lot.